# VB.NET MySQL and FTP Connections

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ftp

I'm working on an application in VB.NET that has to connect to a MySQL database and FTP. How secure is it if I used it in an application that I gave to other people. E.g. if I was to let other people use this application would they be able to find out the MySQL and FTP connection details through intercepting packets or something like that?

If that's the case how can I work round this? Also, part of my application is an uploader for users to upload files, is FTP secure for that or are there better alternatives ways in doing that? My server is a Windows Server 08 if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP is plaintext. It is very easy to get user names and passwords just by packet sniffing. If the ftp is supposed to be secure rather look ay sftp or ftps solutions. These use SSL type encryption on the network layer. Never ever use a ftp server for sensitive information.

MySQL traffic can also be sniffed though it is considerably harder to reverse engineer the protocol. If data has to flow between client and mysql in a secured fashion you can configure mysql to use SSL certificates to encrypt the information. This will ensure security is of highest standards.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but as per [Accessing SQL Server with Explicit Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984237%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) article and it is applicable to MySql as well:

> The recommended method is to store the predetermined user name and
>   password on the server, and then read it and add it to the connection
>   string at run time. An advantage of this technique is that your
>   application can access the database using different credentials under
>   different circumstances, depending on what it needs to do in the
>   database.
>
> **Security Note**   Never hard-code credentials as strings into programs in your application. Anyone who can get access to the code
>   file, even the compiled code, will be able to get at the credentials.
>
> **Security Note**   Always give a predetermined user name the minimal access privileges to a resource. Never use "sa" or any other
>   administrative-level user name. Always use passwords